# __CFNSString to NSString loses special chars

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding, nsstring, nscfstring

I have a weird issue. I have a UTF-8 encoded json which is converted to models via RestKit.

When I view the contents of my model I get a nice string with special chars with phrases like `"los kaartje €17,50 (o.a. te koop"` (notice the €-sign)

Now when I save the value in a NSString like this:

```
NSString *placeholder = self.event.description;
```

My string suddenly becomes `los kaartje ?17,50 (o.a. te koop` (notice the €-sign being gone).

I can't figure out why. The only thing I noticed is that `self.event.description` is a `__NSCFString *` instead of a `NSString *`

Comment: __NSCFString is a (private) subclass of the NSString class cluster, that is not the problem. How is self.event created from the JSON data?

Comment: Using RestKit's objectmapping.

Comment: In the two cases how are you viewing the contents of your string?

Comment: Using the debugger, both times. It's even the same line of code.

Comment: Instead of using `description` you probably better use methods such as `stringWithFormat` to create a string from the object. E.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.event.item, self.item.price]`

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work...But `description` is not a object, nor is it the the description of the object, it is just a property (type `NSString *`) of the event object.

Comment: @DaanOlislagers: What kind of object is `self.event`?

Comment: It is a custom Event class. Nothing special, just a few NSString's and a few methods.

Comment: I found it! How could I be so dumb. description had a custom getter method. Which did this: `return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`.. So no UTF-8. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Remark: `description` is an `NSObject` method and meant to return a a string that represents the contents of the object. You can override that in a subclass, but using `description` for a single attribute of your class might be confusing for other people that have to work with your code.